# What is the phrase for a romantic relationship between two incompatible personality types?

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the phrase for a romantic relationship between two incompatible personality types?

Example: nerd & party animal.

Often seen in movies, lots of examples e.g. "Hometown Cha Cha Cha";  "Pretty Woman", etc.

C.f. "May-December romance" ... but for personality, not age.

Edit:  Someone below asked for the context where this is needed.  It is in Wikipedia article:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hometown_Cha-Cha-Cha       There is a sentence I want to improve:  "... The drama depicts tiki-taka romance between the two and life  of other Gongjin's residents."    By "tiki-taka" they mean oil-and-water, but I want to replace it with a better phrase.  But I'm having trouble finding one.  Tho "oil and water" is not bad.

Comment: Presumably you mean _apparently_ incompatible?

Comment: There's a difference between complementary personality types (e.g. a leader and a follower, a dominant and a submissive), and genuinely incompatible (which might very different, but might be two leaders, two who are both too indecisive, or two who are otherwise too similar).

Comment: Can you provide more of the context in which the word will be used?

Comment: oil and water...?

Answer (score 5):

The relevant idiomatic expression even gets its own ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opposites%20attract#:%7E:text=idiom,often%20attracted%20to%20each%20other)) dictionary entry...

> **opposites attract** (idiom)
> *used to say that people who are very different from each other are often attracted to each other*

If people didn't recognize the truth of that saying, they probably wouldn't be prepared to watch endless movies based on it, because they wouldn't find the scenario convincing.

A well-known example rooted in the *physical* (rather than emotional) sphere is [*the **north** and **south** poles of a magnet.*](https://ece.northeastern.edu/fac-ece/nian/mom/work.html)

---

I'd guess there's a sound biological / evolutionary reason for this tendency. It leads to better mixing of the human gene pool, and "[any fule kno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any_fule_kno)" that mongrel dogs are often far healthier than inbred pedigree dogs. It was probably a risky business, but the genetic evidence is that *homo sapiens* definitely interbred with Neanderthals!

Answer (score 3):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mismatch) has a word with an appropriate usage example

> **mismatch**
> *verb*
>
> to put together people or things that are unsuitable for each other:
>
> *I always thought Chris and Monique were mismatched, so I wasn't surprised when they got divorced.*